# CSS: max-width for @media query not working at certain div tags

Tags: html, css

> max-width: 700px not working in id="wrap2"
>
> But with id="wrapper", its working fine. (Right now it is commented)

```
<style type="text/css">
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  /*#wrapper {
display: none;
}*/
  #wrap2{
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
<div style="display: inline; float: left;">
   A
</div>


<div style="display: inline; float: right;" id="wrap2">
 B
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using inline css. You can use `!important` to change the inline property.

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #wrap2{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="display: inline; float: left;">
   A
</div>

<div style="display: inline; float: right;" id="wrap2">
 B
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! :-)  it worked completely fine. But I don't understand why that happened.

Comment: Browsers decide which property values to use by their specificity. Inline styles always have the highest specificity (which can only be overwritten by `!important` rules). For more information visit MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @AjinkyaRathod Also, this helps you a lot: https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/css-specificity-wars.png

Answer (score 0):

If you use external CSS instead of inline and then you include this file in html it work.